# Why my Blender is incredibly slow

Tags: workflow

Configuration of my computer is
I9 10th gen 10900k
Nvdia 2080super 8 gb
64gb ram
Blender version: 2.92

I was using blender to sculpt a z brush model of 6 million poly around 4-5 months ago. But when i open the same blender file the software is slow and cant do anything. The frame rate after adding keyframes is 0.2fps. Its the same with any high poly models. Any solution for this?

Thanks Arun

Comment: 6 million poly is huge. But if it was running all right before, this might be because 2.92 is in alpha stage and does not yet have memory optimization or something. As a PS, 2.92 might be released now, but I’m not aware of it yet since I haven’t checked their site in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the information.I was working in 2.83

Comment: Are you sure you need the 6 milion polygons??? *cries in i3-3120M 6gb*

Comment: I am a newbie to this area, slowly learning. Could you please recommend whats the optimal polygon number, it depends on the project though.?